# Arduino + esp8266 + mqtt

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266

I have a `mqtt` + `nodejs` server for my smart home system. First , I am trying to blink a led from my `mqtt` + `nodejs` server.

I made this with `nodemcu` a board. I used `pubsubclient.h` for this, but I wanted to add more sensors and leds. Because of that, I decided to use Arduino mega + esp8266. I want to connect to my server via esp8266. The problem is I can't use `pubsubclient.h` with the Arduino mega + esp8266.

And I started using AT Commands to connect to a wifi. Now, I can connect to wifi, but I don't know how can I use mqtt now.

I found a library `espduino`, but it needs special connections.

How can I use AT commands and Mqtt for my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mqtt between esp8266 and arduino with PubSubclient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030019/mqtt-between-esp8266-and-arduino-with-pubsubclient)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to use a multiplexer instead (like the [4051](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4051.pdf)). You can than expand 4 IO ports to 8 IO's (or 1 analog + 3 IO to 8 analog ports). If you want even more ports get something like a [4067](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4067B.pdf), then you can get 16 ports out of 5.

The esp8266 is much more powerful than a normal Arduino (with an ATMEGA328 chip), it's also cheaper than the ArduinoMega, so try to keep it as your microcontroller (if you are already using it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to denote a WiFi or Ethernel client instance to establish connection to the broker via MQTT libraries. So, while doing serial communication, you need to have a serial Arduino library which work with ESP and implements protocol headers and stacks.

You can use [WiFiEsp library](https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp/tree/master/) to create a client instance of WiFi. So you will be able to pass your client as parameter to the PubSubClient constructor. Here is example :

```
WiFiEspClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
```

Another serial library is [espduino](https://github.com/tuanpmt/espduino) as you mentioned. You can follow its guide and use the MQTT library of Arduino like that :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <espduino.h>
#include <mqtt.h>

SoftwareSerial debugPort(2, 3); // RX, TX
ESP esp(&Serial, &debugPort, 4);
MQTT mqtt(&esp);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you try [Homie-esp8266](https://github.com/marvinroger/homie-esp8266). I think it will fit your current setup. It supports MQTT, easy wifi configuration and Over The Air (OTA) firmware update. The [documentation](https://homie-esp8266.readme.io/) is pretty straight forward as well. It's what I use  currently in my smart home project.